# Orphan IBM JVM process

Tags: websphere, jython, windows-server-2003, wsadmin

I have this issue about orphan IBM JVM process being created in the process tree:

For example:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin>wsadmin -lang jython -f "C:\Hello.py"
```

Hello.py has the simple implementation:

```
import time

i = 0

while (1):
    i = i + 1
    print "Hello World " + str(i)
    time.sleep(3.0)
```

My machine has such JVM information:

```
C:\Program Files\WebSphere\java\bin>java -verbose:sizes -version
  -Xmca32K        RAM class segment increment
  -Xmco128K       ROM class segment increment
  -Xmns0K         initial new space size
  -Xmnx0K         maximum new space size
  -Xms4M          initial memory size
  -Xmos4M         initial old space size
  -Xmox1624995K   maximum old space size
  -Xmx1624995K    memory maximum
  -Xmr16K         remembered set size
  -Xlp4K          large page size
                  available large page sizes: 4K 4M
  -Xmso256K       operating system thread stack size
  -Xiss2K         java thread stack initial size
  -Xssi16K        java thread stack increment
  -Xss256K        java thread stack maximum size
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwi3260sr6ifix-20091015_01(SR6+152211+155930+156106))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows Server 2003 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr6-20091001_43491 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20091001_043491
JIT  - r9_20090902_1330ifx1
GC   - 20090817_AA)
JCL  - 20091006_01
```

While the program is running, I tried to kill it and subsequently I found an orphan IBM JVM process in the process tree. Is there a way to fix this issue? Why is there an orphan process in the first place? Is there something wrong with my code?

I really don't believe that my simplistic code is wrongly implemented. Any suggestions?

Comment: how did you (tried to) kill the script

Comment: Since this is done in Windows, I right-clicked at the console icon (the parent of the JVM process) and then select kill process. The JVM wasn't killed instead it got orphaned.

Comment: I'm afraid this is by design of the wsadmin.